# extract keywords form images using python

Tags: python, xml, image, metafile

still learning python. I am currently working on a python code that will extracts metadata (usermade keywords) from images.
I already tried Pillow AND exif but this excludes the user made tags or keywords. 
With applist, i successfully managed to extract the metafile including my keywords but when I tried to purse it with ElementTree to extract the parts of interest, I obtain only empty data.

My xml file look like this (after some manipulation):

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 4.4.0">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
         <dc:description>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">South Carolina, Olivyana, Kumasi</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:description>
         <dc:subject>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li>Kumasi</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>Summer 2016</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>Charlestone</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>SC</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>Beach</rdf:li>
               <rdf:li>Olivjana</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </dc:subject>
         <dc:title>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">P1050365</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:title>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:aux="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/">
         <aux:SerialNumber>F360908190331</aux:SerialNumber>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

My code looks like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
with Image.open("myfile.jpg") as im:
    for segment, content in im.applist:
        marker, body = content.split(b'\x00', 1)
        if segment == 'APP1' and marker == b'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/':
            data = body.decode('"utf-8"')
print (data)
```

at this point it was't possible to pass this to the parser as there is an empty line returning an error:

```
tree = ET.parse(data)

ValueError: embedded null byte
```

so after removing it i saved the data in a xml file (the xml data above) and passed to the parser but obtaining no data:

```
tree = ET.parse('mytags.xml')
tags = tree.findall('xmpmeta/RDF/Description/subject/Bags')
print (type(tags))
print (len(tags))

<class 'list'>
0
```

Interestingly, it I used the tags in the form of the xml file (i.e. 'x:xmpmeta':), I receive the following error:

```
SyntaxError: prefix 'x' not found in prefix map
```

Thanks for your help.

Fabio

Comment: What is it exactly that you want as an output ?

Comment: It should be possible to parse using ElementTree, so please post the code that didn't work.

Comment: Codes added, there were aseries of little problems I tried to fix as well. i am interested in the ,rdf:li> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing only on your XML parsing not PIL metadata work, three issues are your problem:

1. You need to define the namespace prefixes when using `findall` which you can do with the *namespaces* arg. And then your xpath must include the prefixes.
2. When using `findall` do not include the root as that is the starting point but from its child downward.
3. There is no *Bags* local name with plural but only *Bag* and its length would be one. If you want its children, go one level deeper.

Consider adjusted script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('mytags.xml')

nmspdict = {'x':'adobe:ns:meta/',            
            'rdf': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#',
            'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'}

tags = tree.findall('rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/dc:subject/rdf:Bag/rdf:li',
                    namespaces = nmspdict)

print (type(tags))
print (len(tags))

# <class 'list'>
# 6

for i in tags:
    print(i.text)
# Kumasi
# Summer 2016
# Charlestone
# SC
# Beach
# Olivjana
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the help and sorry for the misspell. I tried to loop across the list created to extract the tags but received the following error:        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Not quite sure what you tried but I updated with a loop iteration.