# Python: Read xmp data from png files

Tags: python, image, png, python-imaging-library, xmp

I have the following problem. I open png images with PIL `Image.open()`. Is there a possiblity to read the xmp data after openening the image? I do not want to open the image twice, like i do it at the moment with `Image.open(path)` and the libxmp library, in which the image is also opened to read the xmp data (`xmp = file_to_dict(path)`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read image XMP data in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822693/read-image-xmp-data-in-python)

Comment: @Alderven Unfornuatley not. It is for jpeg files:(

Comment: Can you share PNG image with XMP data?

Answer (score 1):

If you use PIL's `Image.open()`, it is in the `text` attribute (and also in the `info` attribute which contains the contents of the text attribute and some more stuff such as the resolution). ...which, in turn is a dict. In the images I looked at, it had only one entry, with key `XML:com.adobe.xmp`, which holds the xmp data.

So you may want to do something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
im = Image.open(/path/tho/image.png)    # replace with correct path
trees = [ET.fromstring(im.text[key]) for key in im.text.keys()]
```

And then you can inspect it, similar to how it is done, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42894012/1735215):

```
for tree in trees:
    nmspdict = {'x':'adobe:ns:meta/',            
            'rdf': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#',
            'dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'}
    tags = tree.findall('rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/dc:subject/rdf:Bag/rdf:li',
                    namespaces = nmspdict)
    tag_contents = [tag.text for tag in tags]
    print(tag_contents)
```